# Windows phone 8 Performance progressbar

Tags: windows-phone-8

Do i need to use performance progressbar in windows phone 8. In my windows phone 7/7.5 application i was used the progressbar shipped with the toolkit(performance progressbar). Is it necessary to use the same in windows phone 8 or simple progress bar is sufficient?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The WP8 SDK contains the improved progress bar now. So use this one only. 
The TK version in not working properly anymore on WP8.

See changes for the SDK here, including a sentence about the progress bar:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

See a discussion about that topic here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/wpdevelop/thread/dd457734-a11a-48e2-8443-ba8f5e3f67ac

Comment: I am a windows phone 8 app developer, as per your provided link, there is no continues show progress, its dotted progress. So if i am downloading any file than it doesn't show proper download, it continues show animated dotts. I want to use performance progressbar  in windows phone 8 app. if you have any link than pls mention.

Answer (score 2):

Use the WP8 SDK's progress bar, but don't forget to set IsIndeterminate = false after collapsing the progressbar.  It will run in the background & use battery & UI thread cycles  even though its collapsed!  :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use something like this when targeting WP7 and WP8 with linked files:

```
#if WP8
    public class MyPerformanceProgressBar : ProgressBar
    {

    }
#else
    public class MyPerformanceProgressBar : Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PerformanceProgressBar
    {

    }
#endif
```

and use the class `MyPerformanceProgressBar` in your XAML code (which is linked in WP7 and WP8 project).